# data type mismatch in criteria expression in MS Access

Tags: regex, ms-access

My First Query is

1)

```
    SELECT [CIN Data].REGISTERED_OFFICE_ADDRESS, Replace([REGISTERED_OFFICE_ADDRESS],' ','') AS Address_WO_Space, [CIN Data].CORPORATE_IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER, [CIN Data].COMPANY_NAME, [CIN Data].COMPANY_STATUS, [CIN Data].COMPANY_CLASS, [CIN Data].COMPANY_CATEGORY, [CIN Data].AUTHORIZED_CAPITAL, [CIN Data].PAIDUP_CAPITAL, [CIN Data].DATE_OF_REGISTRATION, [CIN Data].REGISTERED_STATE, [CIN Data].REGISTRAR_OF_COMPANIES, [CIN Data].PRINCIPAL_BUSINESS_ACTIVITY, [CIN Data].SUB_CATEGORY
FROM [CIN Data]
WHERE ((([CIN Data].REGISTERED_OFFICE_ADDRESS) Not Like ""));
```

My 2nd Query is

```
 SELECT regexp([Pin Code].[Address_WO_Space],"[0-9]{6}") AS PinCode, [Pin Code].Address_WO_Space, [Pin Code].CORPORATE_IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER, [Pin Code].COMPANY_NAME, [Pin Code].COMPANY_STATUS, [Pin Code].COMPANY_CLASS, [Pin Code].COMPANY_CATEGORY, [Pin Code].AUTHORIZED_CAPITAL, [Pin Code].PAIDUP_CAPITAL, [Pin Code].DATE_OF_REGISTRATION, [Pin Code].REGISTERED_STATE, [Pin Code].REGISTRAR_OF_COMPANIES, [Pin Code].PRINCIPAL_BUSINESS_ACTIVITY, [Pin Code].SUB_CATEGORY, [Pin Code].REGISTERED_OFFICE_ADDRESS
FROM [Pin Code]
WHERE (((regexp([Pin Code].[Address_WO_Space],"[0-9]{6}")) Not Like ""));


    Function regexp( _  StringToCheck As Variant, _  PatternToUse As Variant, _
  Optional CaseSensitive As Boolean = True)   Dim re As New regexp   re.Pattern = PatternToUse   re.Global = False   re.IgnoreCase = Not CaseSensitive   Dim m   For Each m In re.Execute(StringToCheck)     regexp = m.Value   Next End Function
```

So Here is what i am looking for.. Need to extract pin code from address i have used  regexp to do the same.. even thought i am getting output i am also getting Blanks which is because address doesn't  have any Pin Code in it ( Pin code eg is XXXXXX )

When i use " Not Like "" ) as criteria or try to sort it gives me data type mismatch in criteria expression in MS Access.

any better way to do that..

All i need my data should come where Pin Code is there ( without any Blank or any other characters ) only 6 digit numbers.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code and format your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `Like` here but:

```
[CIN Data].REGISTERED_OFFICE_ADDRESS <> ""
```

or more likely:

```
[CIN Data].REGISTERED_OFFICE_ADDRESS Is Not Null
```